# "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Activity has been destroyed" when press onBackPressed()

Tags: java, android, exception, android-fragments, illegalstateexception

I have an activity with an animated fragment. When I press on backpressed to close the activity I get this error. What does it mean?

```
  01-24 12:41:24.407: E/AndroidRuntime(23621):    FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 01-24 12:41:24.407: E/AndroidRuntime(23621):     java.lang.IllegalStateException: Activity has been destroyed
 01-24 12:41:24.407: E/AndroidRuntime(23621):   at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction(FragmentManager.java:1351)
 01-24 12:41:24.407: E/AndroidRuntime(23621):   at android.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(BackStackRecord.java:595)
 01-24 12:41:24.407: E/AndroidRuntime(23621):   at android.app.BackStackRecord.commit(BackStackRecord.java:574)
 01-24 12:41:24.407: E/AndroidRuntime(23621):   at com.eni.enim4s.TranslucentActivity$1.run(TranslucentActivity.java:70)
 01-24 12:41:24.407: E/AndroidRuntime(23621):   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
 01-24 12:41:24.407: E/AndroidRuntime(23621):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
 01-24 12:41:24.407: E/AndroidRuntime(23621):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
 01-24 12:41:24.407: E/AndroidRuntime(23621):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5279)
 01-24 12:41:24.407: E/AndroidRuntime(23621):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 01-24 12:41:24.407: E/AndroidRuntime(23621):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
 01-24 12:41:24.407: E/AndroidRuntime(23621):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
 01-24 12:41:24.407: E/AndroidRuntime(23621):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
 01-24 12:41:24.407: E/AndroidRuntime(23621):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

My code:

```
  public class TranslucentActivity extends Activity {

private Fragment fragment;
private FrameLayout frame;
private android.app.FragmentTransaction ft;
private android.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.translucent);

     frame =(FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.container);
  }

@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
        frame.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         fragment = new ViewDetail();
         fragmentManager = getFragmentManager(); 
         ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction(); 
        ft.setCustomAnimations(R.animator.trans_left_in,R.animator.trans_left_out);
        ft.addToBackStack(null); 
        ft.replace(R.id.container, fragment, "Dettaglio"); 
        ft.commit();//the error is here


            }
        }, 500);
}




 @Override
     public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    this.finish();
   }
```

}

Comment: Why would you keep the  `//TODO Auto-generated method stub` text of Eclipse in your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can just remove this `onBackPressed` as android implicitly finishes your activity on back key pressed.

And don't call `addToBackStack`:

```
ft.addToBackStack(null);
```

remove the above line this adds your fragment transaction in backstack and on back key pressed first transaction is reverted and then activity is finished.

If you remove this back press will finish the activity.

change to:

```
    if(hasFocus){
    frame.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

    @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     fragment = new ViewDetail();
     fragmentManager = getFragmentManager(); 
     ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction(); 
    ft.setCustomAnimations(R.animator.trans_left_in,R.animator.trans_left_out);
    ft.addToBackStack(null); 
    ft.replace(R.id.container, fragment, "Dettaglio"); 
    ft.commit();//the error is here


        }
    }, 500);
  }
```

Comment: have you removed your implementation of onBackPressed?

Comment: Yes, I removed onBackPressed()

Comment: are you pressing back button before 500ms??

Comment: Even after it happens the same

Comment: the thing is onFocus change is called even when you move out of the window so just check if window is getting focus and then call post delay

Comment: to handle such a case. Override the onBackKeyPress and set a boolean that back key has been pressed, and in the run method of post delayed first check if the back key is not pressed and then only add a fragment.

Answer (score 4):

The error is not happening on the line

```
this.finish();//the error is here
```

it's most likely happening on

```
ft.commit();
```

What happens is that, when you see this error, this code runs *after* the activity has been destroyed, so there is no `FragmentManager` or any `Activity` state to work with, thus the transaction cannot be committed.

This happens because you run this code after a delay, and if you press back the window focus changes and the task gets scheduled, but the activity is destroyed before the task actually starts.

What you could do is add a `if (!isFinishing())` check before you run your UI changes inside the task, but I would advise that you rethink your UI flow a little bit. *If* you want the transaction to run after a delay but before the app finishes, then move the `finish()` instruction to the end of the task's `run()` (whether this is UI-wise a good user experience or not).

Note also that you shouldn't have to do both

```
super.onBackPressed();
this.finish();//the error is here
```

in `onBackPressed()`: either you do some custom action (e.g. finishing the app) *to replace* the default behavior, *or* you leave it to the original (`super`) behavior.

Comment: I removed the method onBackPressed() but I get the same error. The error begin in **ft.commit**

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm saying in my answer, read it once more ;) Even if you remove your `onBackPressed()`, the default `onBackPressed()` behavior will be executed when press the back button and it usually finishes the `Activity` which would mean that its window loses focus and `onWindowFocusChanged()` gets called anyway. Again, look at the solutions I suggested and understand why it's happening (it's because you're doing UI work _after_ the activity has been destroyed).

Comment: The !isFinishing() worked for me, thanks for the good explanation as well!

Comment: Do `isFinishing()` return true if the activity has **already** been finished?

Answer (score -1):

```
@Override
     public void onBackPressed() {
      super.onBackPressed() 

   }
```

Remove this line  `this.finish() ;`

actually  `super.onBackPressed()` finish your activity

Comment: super.onBackPressed() remove only fragment animated on activity not the activity. There is a error in **ft.commit()** in method **run()**